# Why doesn't this code cause a TypeScript type error?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript1.5

With interfaces defined like so:

```
interface IRemoteService {
  createRecord(record: RecordType): ng.IPromise<ICreateResponse<string>>;
}

interface ICreateResponse<T> {
  createdId: T;
}
```

Why doesn't the following code cause a Typescript compilation error?

```
class RemoteServiceMock implements IRemoteService {
  public static $inject = ["$q"];

  constructor(private $q: ng.IQService){
  }

  createRecord(record: RecordType): ng.IPromise<ICreateResponse<string>> {
    return this.$q.when({});
  }
}
```

The type of `$q.when` is `when<T>(value: T): IPromise<T>`.

Comment: Yes... "{}" is of type "Any" because "Any" is not a type... in that it is "any type".

Comment: Surely {} is of type Object?

Comment: Yes... but any type can be of type "any". Its the same as saying... "anything".... which "object" also satisfies... obviously.

Comment: What I meant by that was "Is {} treated like <any>{}", but you're right, that's probably not clear. Edited.

Comment: What is the definition of `ICreateResponse`?

Comment: It contains a `createdId: T`; I've edited the question with the full definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is according to spec. Here is your example simplified:

```
interface A{
}
interface B {
  createdId: string;
}

var foo:ng.IPromise<A>;
var bar:ng.IPromise<B>;
bar = foo; // No error
```

This assignment is allowed if A is a subtype of B or B is a subtype of A. If this is not the case you will get an error as shown below:

```
interface A {
  breakTypeCompat: number;
}
interface B {
  createdId: string;
}

var foo:ng.IPromise<A>;
var bar:ng.IPromise<B>;
bar = foo; // Error
```

The reason is the bivariance compatibility of function arguments. See this link for docs + reason why this is the way it is: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Type-Compatibility#function-argument-bivariance

## Details

### Background

Type compatibility of the interfaces depends upon how you use them. E.g. the following is not an error :

```
interface IPromise<T>{  
}

interface A{
}
interface B {
  createdId: string;
}

var foo:IPromise<A>;
var bar:IPromise<B>;
bar = foo; // No error
```

However if the `IPromise` where to use the type parameter as a member it would error:

```
interface IPromise<T>{
    member:T    
}

interface A{    
}
interface B {
  createdId: string;
}

var foo:IPromise<A>;
var bar:IPromise<B>;
bar = foo; // Error
```

### Therefore

In the actual promise definition we have something like:

```
interface IPromise<T> {
    then(successCallback: (promiseValue: T) => any): any;
}

interface A {
}
interface B {
    createdId: string;
}

var foo: IPromise<A>;
var bar: IPromise<B>;
bar = foo; // No Error
```

Since we are using `T` as an argument to the a *function* `A` and `B` will be type checked by bivariance. So if A is a subset of B or B is a subset of A they are compatible.

Comment: The example above certainly works.
Sorry to ask a question on top of a question, but why is that allowed? 
A does not implement B, so that would seem to damage the usefulness of interface membership quite a lot.

Comment: Thanks! Makes much more sense now. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain why you're not getting an error, but I do have a suggestion on how to get a warning. According to angular.d.ts `when` is defined like this:

```
when<T>(value: IPromise<T>): IPromise<T>;
when<T>(value: T): IPromise<T>;
when(): IPromise<void>;
```

So if you'd like to use `when` with more typing then use:

```
return this.$q.when<ICreateResponse<string>>({});
```

Comment: Thanks, this did actually give me an error which is great.